# Python Polars - Create sequence in list from integer

Tags: python, python-polars

Considering that:

> Using [apply](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.apply.html#polars.Expr.apply) is strongly discouraged as you will be effectively running python “for” loops. This will be very slow. Wherever possible you should strongly prefer the native expression API to achieve the best performance.

How can I use Polars native expression API to generate a new column with a list containing all the integers from 1 to the number of another column?

This means, going from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Using apply:

```
# Import package.
import polars as pl

# Create the DataFrame.
df = pl.DataFrame({'Qty': [1, 2, 3]})

# Add the 'List' column.
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col('Qty').apply(lambda x: [i+1 for i in range(x)]).alias('List')
)
```

Comment: This is initialization code, not code that you're going to be executing over and over.  In other words, this is not going to be a performance bottleneck.  `apply` is just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pl.int_ranges()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.int_ranges.html)

```
df.with_columns(list = pl.int_ranges(1, pl.col("Qty") + 1))
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ Qty ┆ list      │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [1]       │
│ 2   ┆ [1, 2]    │
│ 3   ┆ [1, 2, 3] │
└─────┴───────────┘
```